# Spring Java JPA: Using specification with hibernate spatial

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-spatial

I am using Spring Boot for a project I'm working on using spatial data. For the spatial data I'm using Hibernate Spatial. This is the configuration for my entity:

```
@Column(name="LOCATION",columnDefinition="geometry(Point,4326)")
private Point location;
```

Where `Point` is of the class `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point`. This also includes a getter and setter.

When retrieving this entity with a normal `repository.findOne("id")` this also includes the location in my result, mapped to a Point. However, I need to have some dynamic query system later on in the system. So therefore I also query data with a class that inherits from `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`. When using this specification, the location is always `null`. The SQL debug information shows me that the location is retrieved from the database, but for some reason, this is not mapped to my entity object.

My spring-boot version is 1.4.0.RELEASE. The data is coming from a mysql database.

Any help to retrieve geometry data with the use of a `Specification` will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tested same with Mysql Spatial and retrieving the data by applying query using Specifications. I could retrieve the spatial data.

Here are the few Pointers you can try with.

1. Make sure you've set the dialect which supports Spatial Query and types.

   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect
2. No need to define Column definition.

Remove `columnDefinition="geometry(Point,4326)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly this does not help. I think that the problem lies within org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor. I do not see an attribute for any geometry type within my generated models. Did I forget something in my plugin definition? I am using maven.

Comment: When I change my definition from Point to Geometry, it gets added to the metamodel, but the value stays null.

Comment: @Cerebres BTW which version of spring-boot and hibernate you are using. I tested with spring-boot 2.0.0 snapshot and hibernate 5.2.5

Comment: I am using:
Spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE
Hibernate-spatial 5.2.2.Final

Comment: Ok, can you post the Dialect you are using?

Comment: I'm using spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect

Comment: Please use org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect. it is the mostly the culprit. I previously used org.hibernate.spatia‌​l.dialect.mysql.MySQ‌​L56InnoDBSpatialDiale‌​ct, it was giving me error.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Unfortunately changing the dialect is not really an option for me.

Comment: Hmm......... In that case you can use Point from org.geolatte.geom.Point as an alternative.